# how can i use a value from outside in axios

Tags: reactjs, axios, use-effect

How can I use the value returned in the export function in another component?
I have a string value (url) in export function
header.js

```
 export default function Header() {
        const [countries] = useState([
          
        ]);

        const [selectedCountry, setSelectedCountry] = useState();
    
        if (selectedCountry === "tr") {
            getLang("tr");
        }
        else if (selectedCountry === "en") {
            getLang("en");
        }
        else {
            getLang("en");
        }
```

api.js
(my databse address localhost:8080/product/en or http://localhost:8080/product/tr )

```
export const function getLang = async (param) => {
    const url = ProductUrl + param;
        return url;
        };
```

I need to call this url in axios in useeffect in other component.

navbar.js
(navbars menu turkish or english so if dropdown select tr  , url tr //  if dropdown select english  , url en)

```
  useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get(how?)
      .then(response => setData(response.data))
      .catch(error => console.log({ error }));
  }, []);
```

thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
// getUrl.js
export const getUrl = (params) => {
  return ProductUrl + params;
}
// or export default
// export default function getUrl(params) {
//   return ProductUrl + params
// }
```

Import it into where you want

```js
import { getUrl } from './your-path'
// or import default
// import getUrl from './your-path'

React.useEffect(() => {
  const url = getUrl(params)
  const fetchData = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await axios.get(url)
      // do something with reponse
    } catch (error) {
      // handle err
    }
  }
  fetchData()

}, [params])
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to import it in the component where you want to use it as --->
import {a} from "filedirectory"
then use it in the component by calling that function as

const urlValue = a()

Comment: Please share the code and if it is right then there will be something wrong with ProductUrl, try logging the values in both function and component to debugg it. Also, please vote and accept the answer

Comment: added code but the whole code is a bit complicated and long

Answer (score 0):

```
useEffect(() => {
const url = a(params);
    axios
      .get(url)
      .then(response => setData(response.data))
      .catch(error => console.log({ error }));
  }, []);
```